# Change Product Image Gallery On Options Select

Tags: product, product-images, color-swatches

I have a configurable product with multiple colors/sizes, and each simple product has its own images. I have three images for the main configurable product. When I pick a color option for the product, the first of the three images changes to the right color, but the other two don't. How can I get the other two to change images?

Answer (score 0):

(In magento official site) there is tutorial for how to setup configurable Swatches i think this will help you !!
[Swatch workflow](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch-workflow.html)

Look more detail on menu navigation : Products->swatches